# How to use for loop in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a very basic ASP.NET MVC project, that uses `C#` for the programming language and `Razor` for its view engine.
I want to generate this HTML markup with `for` loop in the view.

```
<div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
<div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
<div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
<div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
<div class="item-5">Item 5</div>
...
<div class="item-N">Item N</div>
```

— Where **`N`** is a defined number in the loop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
   <div class="item-@i">Item @i</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use something like this

```
@for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    <div class="item-@i"> Item @i </div>
}
```

Take a look at this for a refence to how to us the `@` symbol in Razor markup. [Razor cheat sheet](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)